# How do I use a button to change the route in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom to route to different components. But I want to change routes by using a button. When I click one of the buttons, the components and URL don't change. No error messages come up either. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
import React from 'react';
import MenuCards from './MenuCards';
import DrinkCards from './DrinkCards';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


class App extends React.Component {

    menuTest = () => {
        return(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Route path='/menu' exact component={MenuCards} />
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }

    drinkTest = () => {
        return(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Route path='/drinks' exact component={DrinkCards} />
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.menuTest}>Menu test</button>
                <button onClick={this.drinkTest}>Drink test</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) you have to set all your Routes between a component called [Switch](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md).

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/drinks" exact component={DrinkCards} />
    <Route path="/menu" exact component={MenuCards} />
</Switch>
```

To change the current route you have to use a component called [NavLink](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md).

```
<NavLink to="/menu">
    <button>Menu test</button>
</NavLink>
```

But be aware that you can only use a NavLink component inside your BrowserRoute compontent.

Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-how-do-i-use-a-button-to-change-the-route-in-react-hoyrw) example.